# How to correctly generate timestamp

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a method that to create timestamp in long long integer format
EX: 1386752892

```
+ (NSNumber *)currentTimestampWithLongLongFormat
{
    double timeStamp = ceil([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000);

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:false];
    NSNumber *timeNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:timeStamp];
    NSString *timeString = [formatter stringFromNumber:timeNumber];

    // NSTimeInterval is defined as double
    return [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[timeString longLongValue]];
}
```

But this will generate 13 digitals number 
EX: 1386752811802

How to fix the problem and generate the correct format of number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 int timestamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Comment: I would use ``NSTimeInterval`` instead of ``int``. That's what the ``timeIntervalSince1970`` returns and it's a C ``double``.

Comment: :D , didn't understand what you are trying to say

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/**
* @param nil
* @return current time in mili second
*
* Fetch the current time stamp
*/

-(NSString *)currentTimeStamp {
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
NSString *timeStamp1 = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDate *curdate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeStamp1];

double unix_timestamp =  [curdate timeIntervalSince1970];
NSString *timeStamp  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",unix_timestamp*1000];
return timeStamp;
}
```

Comment: for anyone skimming through this,  NSDateFormatter should be used with caution as it can slow you code down.

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (NSString*) dateFromString:(NSString*)aStr

{
    NSDateFormatter *formater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formater setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
    NSDate *date2 = [formater dateFromString:aStr];
    [formater setDateFormat:@"d MMM,yyyy HH:mm"];
    NSString *result = [formater stringFromDate:date2];


    return result;
}

+ (NSString *)calculateTime:(NSString *)datetime :(NSString *)servertime

{


    NSString *time;

    NSDate *date1;
    NSDate *date2;
    {
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
        date1 = [formatter dateFromString:datetime];
        date2 = [formatter dateFromString:servertime];

    }


    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *differenceComponents = [calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit)
                                                         fromDate:date1
                                                           toDate:date2
                                                          options:0];

    NSTimeInterval interval = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate: date2];//[date1 timeIntervalSince1970] - [date2 timeIntervalSince1970];
    int hour = interval / 3600;
    int minute = (int)interval % 3600 / 60;
    int seconds = (int)interval % 60;
    hour=ABS(hour);
    minute=ABS(minute);
    seconds=ABS(seconds);
    if ([differenceComponents day]>0) {
        time=  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld %@", (long)[differenceComponents day],[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"daysago", nil)]];
    }
    else
    {
        if ([differenceComponents day] == 0) {
            time=  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld %@", (long)[differenceComponents day],[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"dayago", nil)]];
            if (hour>0) {
                time= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@", ABS(hour),[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"hourago", nil)]];
            }
            else {
                time=  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@", ABS(hour),[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"hoursago", nil)]];

                if (minute>0) {

                    time= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@", ABS(minute),[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"minuteago", nil)]];
                }
                else {
                    time= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@", ABS(minute),[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"minuteago", nil)]];
                    if (seconds>0) {
                        time= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@", ABS(seconds),[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"secondago", nil)]];
                    }
                    else {
                        time= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@", ABS(seconds),[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"secondsago", nil)]];
                    }

                }
            }

        }

    }

    return time;
}
```

/// as per requirement we will use date formats